Alignment issues of elements
I need some help as I am a complete newbie when it comes to HTML and CSS.  
I am trying to create something like this:

I can generate the entire container itself but the placement of the Blog Title, Blog Post Date, Blog Summary and Read More button are all formatting out bad.  So far the only thing I can place correctly is the img container.
The Image below is the result I get:



  body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Bai Jamjuree", sans-serif;
  /* Adjust with the exact font if found */
}


/* Style for Blog Container */

.blog-container {
  width: 1240px;
  overflow: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  position: relative;
  left: -3px;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 94%;
  /* Responsive for smaller screens */
  padding: 5px 20px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.blog-post {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.blog-thumbnail {
  flex: 1;
}

.blog-thumbnail img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  margin-right: 20px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.blog-post {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 20px;
  max-width: 1200px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  transition: transform 0.3s ease, box-shadow 0.3s ease;
  text-align: left;
}

.blog-post h2 {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  color: #333;
}

.blog-post p {
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #666;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.blog-post a {
  color: #1e7cd6;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.blog-post a:hover {
  color: #104e8b;
}


/* Responsive Styles */

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .blog-search-sort {
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 10px;
  }
  .blog-post {
    width: 95%;
  }
}

.bai-jamjuree-extralight {
  font-family: "Bai Jamjuree", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-style: normal;
}

.bai-jamjuree-light {
  font-family: "Bai Jamjuree", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: normal;
}

.bai-jamjuree-regular {
  font-family: "Bai Jamjuree", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}

.bai-jamjuree-medium {
  font-family: "Bai Jamjuree", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: normal;
}

.bai-jamjuree-semibold {
  font-family: "Bai Jamjuree", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-style: normal;
}

.bai-jamjuree-bold {
  font-family: "Bai Jamjuree", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: normal;
}

.bai-jamjuree-extralight-italic {
  font-family: "Bai Jamjuree", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-style: italic;
}

.bai-jamjuree-light-italic {
  font-family: "Bai Jamjuree", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: italic;
}

.bai-jamjuree-regular-italic {
  font-family: "Bai Jamjuree", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: italic;
}

.bai-jamjuree-medium-italic {
  font-family: "Bai Jamjuree", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: italic;
}

.bai-jamjuree-semibold-italic {
  font-family: "Bai Jamjuree", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-style: italic;
}

.bai-jamjuree-bold-italic {
  font-family: "Bai Jamjuree", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: italic;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a.fill-div {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
)
<div class="blog-container" id="blogContainer">
  <!-- Example Blog Post -->
  <div class="blog-post" data-date="2024-08-30" onclick="';" style="cursor: pointer;">
    <div class="blog-thumbnail">
      <img src="https://d150u0abw3r906.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/aerial-shot.jpg" alt="Thumbnail" />
    </div>
    <h2>How Drone Photography Can Elevate Your Real Estate Listings</h2>
    <p>August 30, 2024</p>
    <p>Unlock the Power of Aerial Views & Attract More Buyers to Your Listings</p>
    <a href="">Read more</a>
  </div>
</div>




Note that you have a typo in CSS line 175: ) instead of }. Besides that, pay extra attention to the word minimal the next time you're posting a [repro]. 175 CSS lines for such a small part are excessive!

I don't think we can give a complete answer until we know a little more about the layout you want to achieve in general cases. For starters, your picture shows a neat fitting of the image height and the adjacent text, what do you want it to look like if a) there isn't sufficient text to 'fill' the second column vertically? and b) are these indeed to be columns (if there is too much text then it stays in that column or does it flow under the image). And is there a limit widthwise on having the 3 columns? Indeed, is it 3 fixed width columns?

I have fixed some mistakes in HTML and CSS i.e., onclick="';" and )
Also removed .blog-thumbnail { flex: 1; }
Fixed some other CSS as well.
Added some div and classes in HTML.
Wrote some CSS for existing and new classes.
Your current code is not responsive for all screen sizes. Please adjust it as well. I have fixed your current issue and tried to make it similar with the output you have added.
Here is the updated code:


body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Bai Jamjuree", sans-serif;
  /* Adjust with the exact font if found */
}

/* Style for Blog Container */

.blog-container {
  width: 1240px;
  overflow: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  position: relative;
  left: -3px;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 94%;
  /* Responsive for smaller screens */
  padding: 5px 20px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.blog-thumbnail img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  margin-right: 20px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.blog-post {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: start;
  height: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 20px;
  max-width: 1200px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  transition: transform 0.3s ease, box-shadow 0.3s ease;
}

.blog-img-and-text {
  display: flex;
}

.blog-post h2 {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  margin: 0 0 15px 0;
  color: #333;
}

.blog-post p {
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #666;
  margin: 0;
}

.blog-post a {
  color: #1e7cd6;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.blog-post a:hover {
  color: #104e8b;
}

/* Responsive Styles */

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .blog-search-sort {
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 10px;
  }
  .blog-post {
    width: 95%;
  }
}

.bai-jamjuree-extralight {
  font-family: "Bai Jamjuree", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-style: normal;
}

.bai-jamjuree-light {
  font-family: "Bai Jamjuree", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: normal;
}

.bai-jamjuree-regular {
  font-family: "Bai Jamjuree", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}

.bai-jamjuree-medium {
  font-family: "Bai Jamjuree", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: normal;
}

.bai-jamjuree-semibold {
  font-family: "Bai Jamjuree", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-style: normal;
}

.bai-jamjuree-bold {
  font-family: "Bai Jamjuree", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: normal;
}

.bai-jamjuree-extralight-italic {
  font-family: "Bai Jamjuree", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-style: italic;
}

.bai-jamjuree-light-italic {
  font-family: "Bai Jamjuree", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: italic;
}

.bai-jamjuree-regular-italic {
  font-family: "Bai Jamjuree", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: italic;
}

.bai-jamjuree-medium-italic {
  font-family: "Bai Jamjuree", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: italic;
}

.bai-jamjuree-semibold-italic {
  font-family: "Bai Jamjuree", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-style: italic;
}

.bai-jamjuree-bold-italic {
  font-family: "Bai Jamjuree", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: italic;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a.fill-div {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.date-and-readmore {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100%;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="blog-container" id="blogContainer">
      <div
        class="blog-post"
        data-date="2024-08-30"
        onclick=""
        style="cursor: pointer"
      >
        <div class="blog-img-and-text">
          <div class="blog-thumbnail">
            <img
              src="https://d150u0abw3r906.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/aerial-shot.jpg"
              alt="Thumbnail"
            />
          </div>

          <div>
            <h2>How Drone Photography Can Elevate Your Real Estate Listings</h2>
            <p>
              Unlock the Power of Aerial Views & Attract More Buyers to Your
              Listings
            </p>
            <p>
              Unlock the Power of Aerial Views & Attract More Buyers to Your
              Listings
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="date-and-readmore">
          <p>August 30, 2024</p>
          <a href="">Read more</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>




CSS-Grid is ideal here.


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-width: 0;
  min-height: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}


/* Style for Blog Container */

.blog-container {
  max-width: 1240px;
  overflow: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  /* Responsive for smaller screens */
  padding: 5px 20px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.blog-post {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
  gap: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.blog-thumbnail {
  grid-row: span 2;
}

.blog-thumbnail img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  object-fit: cover;
}

.blog-post {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 8px;
  max-width: 1200px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  transition: transform 0.3s ease, box-shadow 0.3s ease;
  text-align: left;
}

.blog-post h2 {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: #333;
}

.blog-post p {
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #666;
}

.blog-post a {
  color: #1e7cd6;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  align-self: end;
}

.blog-post a:hover {
  color: #104e8b;
}
<div class="blog-container" id="blogContainer">
  <!-- Example Blog Post -->
  <div class="blog-post" data-date="2024-08-30" onclick="';" style="cursor: pointer;">
    <div class="blog-thumbnail">
      <img src="https://d150u0abw3r906.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/aerial-shot.jpg" alt="Thumbnail" />
    </div>
    <h2>How Drone Photography Can Elevate Your Real Estate Listings</h2>
    <p>August 30, 2024</p>
    <p>Unlock the Power of Aerial Views & Attract More Buyers to Your Listings Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt iste rerum perferendis ab voluptate optio repudiandae at, ratione inventore laboriosam officia? </p>
    <a href="">Read more</a>
  </div>
</div>




You should change the structure a bit and use semantic tags.
In your image, you have 3 columns that you can align next to each other with Flexbox. 
The semantic correct approach would be to use aside as containers for the image and the date and read more columns. The main column with your blog post would be an article.
You can let the article column span the whole available width by using flex-grow: 1.
To let the date and read more columns reach your intended layout you have to use flexbox with flex-direction: column. That way you can add margin-top: auto on the "read more" link to push it to the very bottom.
PS: You should not sue margins to spread columns apart within flexbox. Use gap instead!


section.blog-post {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1.25em;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 20px;
  max-width: 1200px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  transition: transform 0.3s ease, box-shadow 0.3s ease;
  text-align: left;
  
  aside.blog-thumbnail img {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    object-fit: cover;
  }
  
  article {
    flex-grow: 1;
    h2 {
      font-size: 1.2em;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      color: #333;
      margin-top: 0;
    }
    p {
      font-size: 1em;
      color: #666;
      margin-bottom: 100px;
    }
  }
  
  aside.blog-date {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    time {
      color: #666;
    }
    a {
      color: #1e7cd6;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-weight: bold;
      margin-top: auto;
    }
  }
}
<main class="blog-container" id="blogContainer">
  <!-- Example Blog Post -->
  <section class="blog-post" data-date="2024-08-30" onclick="';" style="cursor: pointer;">
    <aside class="blog-thumbnail">
      <img src="https://d150u0abw3r906.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/aerial-shot.jpg" alt="Thumbnail" />
    </aside>
    <article>
      <h2>How Drone Photography Can Elevate Your Real Estate Listings</h2>
      <p>Unlock the Power of Aerial Views & Attract More Buyers to Your Listings</p>
    </article>
    <aside class="blog-date">
      <time datetime="2024-08-30">August 30, 2024</time>   
      <a href="">Read more</a>
    </aside>
  </section>
</main>




This is not responsive at all. Read OP's requirements again.

media queries have not been added because they are irrelevant to the question itself. The alignment has nothing to do with responsiveness. Good answers focus on the issue and cut the rest away to keep the code short.

Why would OP then include media queries in the code if they are not relevant?

because the Op clearly didn't cut down the code to the necessary part. The question was not about how to make his code responsive but how to reach the intended layout. That intended layout purely depends on 3 columns.

You need one more wrapper for typography elements.


body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Bai Jamjuree", sans-serif;
  /* Adjust with the exact font if found */
}

/* Style for Blog Container */

.blog-container {
  width: 1240px;
  overflow: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  position: relative;
  left: -3px;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 94%;
  /* Responsive for smaller screens */
  padding: 5px 20px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.blog-thumbnail img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  margin-right: 20px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.blog-post {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 20px;
  max-width: 1200px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  transition: transform 0.3s ease, box-shadow 0.3s ease;
  text-align: left;
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.blog-post h2 {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  color: #333;
}

.blog-post p {
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #666;
}

.blog-post a {
  color: #1e7cd6;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.blog-post a:hover {
  color: #104e8b;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* Responsive Styles */

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .blog-post {
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 10px;
  }
}
<div class="blog-container" id="blogContainer">
  <!-- Example Blog Post -->
  <div class="blog-post" data-date="2024-08-30" onclick="';" style="cursor: pointer;">
    <div class="blog-thumbnail">
      <img src="https://d150u0abw3r906.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/aerial-shot.jpg" alt="Thumbnail" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <h2>How Drone Photography Can Elevate Your Real Estate Listings</h2>
      <p>August 30, 2024</p>
      <p>Unlock the Power of Aerial Views & Attract More Buyers to Your Listings</p>
      <p>Unlock the Power of Aerial Views & Attract More Buyers to Your Listings</p>

      <a href="">Read more</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



Also, you have a lot of smelly CSS in your code, magic numbers like 94%. Try to make your layout fluid, instead of hardcoding fixed values. This article might help you: https://csswizardry.com/2012/11/code-smells-in-css/

While I agree on that 94%is not clean, it is not a fixed value. Percentages are responsive values and complies with RWD rules.

The given snippet does not give the required layout. For example, on full page on my laptop the date is incorrectly positioned.

@tacoshy there is a smelly css all over the place. I did not see that date in the corner in the image.

read again. I agree that it is not clean. It however is incorrect to state that percentages are fixed values. They are not, they are responsive.

I was referring to other hard coded values like left: -3px. 94% is percentage, I agree, it is not fixed.
